# Go Printing in VSCode

Tags: go, printing

A bit confused on why the following code does not print anything in vscode using the go extension (and properly installed Go)

```
import "fmt"

func main() { 
    fmt.Println("Hello World!")
}
```

Nothing at all gets outputted.

If I remove the exclamation mark within in the print statement
It prints out `Hello World`

Comment: Why not just use `go run .` instead? there's nothing wrong with the code.

Comment: Please provide extra detail; how are you attempting to run the application?

Comment: it runs perfectly , may be you forget to add at the first line  `package main`   . https://go.dev/play/p/SDx5_QNEaoO

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this might be your answer:
[Go installed successfully but no output with simple Hello World](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76786165/go-installed-successfully-but-no-output-with-simple-hello-world)

TLDR: Antivirus programs on Windows (in my case, MalwareBytes) don't play well with executables.  What worked for me was either turning off MalwareBytes or adding the folders where main.exe to the allowed list (along with any/all folders containing Go-related binaries).

Answer (score -2):

Maybe this:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() { 
    fmt.Println("Hello World!");
}
```

```bash
→ go build main.go
→ ./main
Hello World!
```

Don't forget the semiocolon at the end of go line and instruction package follow by name of package at the beginning of the file.

Comment: "Don't forget the semiocolon"; the semicolon is valid but unnecessary (See the [language specification](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Semicolons) for details).