# Go installed successfully but no output with simple Hello World

Tags: windows, go

Using Windows 11 Pro, installed Go using the [installer](https://go.dev/doc/install).
Here is my main.go file:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello world")
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
}
```

And all relevant info I can think of:
**Powershell version:**
`PS C:\Users\fares.alghazy\go\src> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion`

Major  Minor  Build  Revision

---

5      1      22621  1778

**GO extension settings.json:**

```
{
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "terminal.integrated.scrollback": 100000,
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "workbench.editorAssociations": {
        "*.db": "default",
        "*.docx": "default"
    },
    "[json]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.json-language-features"
    },
    "[php]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "Sophisticode.php-formatter"
    },
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "prettier.tabWidth": 4,
    "[typescript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features"
    },
    "[dockercompose]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-azuretools.vscode-docker"
    },
    "typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
    "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
    "[jsonc]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "[html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "[typescriptreact]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features"
    },
    "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": false,
    "workbench.startupEditor": "none",
    "[vue]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "Vue.volar"
    },
    "audioCues.lineHasBreakpoint": "off",
    "audioCues.lineHasError": "off",
    "audioCues.lineHasInlineSuggestion": "off",
    "audioCues.noInlayHints": "off",
    "audioCues.onDebugBreak": "off",
    "audioCues.volume": 0,
    "audioCues.lineHasFoldedArea": "off",
    "go.gopath": "C:\\Users\\myuser\\go",
    "go.goroot": "C:\\Program Files\\Go",
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "go.alternateTools": {
    
    }
}
```

**System/Directory Info:**

```
PS C:\Users\myuser\go\src> pwd

C:\Users\myuser\go\src


PS C:\Users\myuser\go\src> ls


    Directory: C:\Users\myuser\go\src


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----         28-Jul-23  12:00 PM            122 main.go


PS C:\Users\myuser\go\src> go version
go version go1.20.6 windows/amd64
PS C:\Users\myuser\go\src> go env
set GO111MODULE=
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOENV=C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\go\env
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOEXPERIMENT=
set GOFLAGS=
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOINSECURE=
set GOMODCACHE=C:\Users\myuser\go\pkg\mod
set GONOPROXY=
set GONOSUMDB=
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\Users\myuser\go
set GOPRIVATE=
set GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org,direct
set GOROOT=C:\Program Files\Go
set GOSUMDB=sum.golang.org
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GOVCS=
set GOVERSION=go1.20.6
set GCCGO=gccgo
set GOAMD64=v1
set AR=ar
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=0
set GOMOD=NUL
set GOWORK=
set CGO_CFLAGS=-O2 -g
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-O2 -g
set CGO_FFLAGS=-O2 -g
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-O2 -g
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -Wl,--no-gc-sections -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=C:\Users\myuser~1.ALG\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build1704880455=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches
```

**The problem:**

**Action run:**
`go run main.go`
**Expected output:**
`> Hello world`
**Received output:**
Terminal stalls (even without the time.sleep) then nothing happens

**Attempted fixes**:
1- Attempted to use go build then running the exe, no output was received
2- Attempted to build then redirect the output to a file:
`go build main.go`
`.\main.exe >output.txt`
output.txt was created but empty
3- Checked console encoding : `Active code page: 65001`
4-Disable Antivirus or Security Software: I am using standard windows security features, no 3rd party security software installed
I have even tried re-installing the Go software, restarting my pc, restarting VS code, etc
**Why is my code not showing output? What can I do to fix it?**
**Update 1:**
As instructed by @mkopriva:
go mod init my_app produce the following go.mod file:

```
module my_app

go 1.20
```

My new directory is:

```
PS C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\Development\go\my_app> ls


Directory: C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\Development\go\my_app


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----         28-Jul-23   1:14 PM             27 go.mod
-a----         28-Jul-23   1:15 PM            125 main.go
```

No changes with go run main.go, or with building then running. Still not getting an output.

Comment: (1.) Do not use `$GOPATH\src` as the direct parent directory of your source files. Move the code to it's own directory, e.g `C:\Users\myuser\my_app\main.go`. (2.) Before running the code you should initialize its module with `go mod init <module_path>` (e.g. `go mod init my_app`)

Comment: You might be tricked by the Windows defender. These "tools" often falsly classify Go programs as malware. Try running `go build main.go` and see if the `.exe` runs. It might get deleted by Windows right after you create it, thus your command line hangs.

Comment: @Volker I have also tried `go run .` with similar results

Comment: @gonutz running `go build main.go` then running the exe directly produces no output, but the file gets deleted after.

Comment: The I suggest you go to your Windows security settings and add an exception to your development folder. I personally had to do this for both my `GOBIN` and `GOPATH` folders, where my executables and code reside. Also, when you use `go run`, the output will be written to a temporary file in your `APPDATA` folder, called `go-build`. You may add this as well.

Comment: @gonutz your answer led me to my correct answer, it was indeed an anti-virus issue. I had a previous installation of an anti-virus software by my coorportation that was not fully removed, after making sure it was fully uninstalled properly a simple ` go run main.go` worked perfectly . So thank you! Post an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go programs are often falsy recognized by anti-virus software to be malicious, even though they are not. There is even [a FAQ entry on this topic](https://go.dev/doc/faq#virus) in the official Go documentation.

Windows defender will often delete your executable file right after compilation. Instead of using `go run main.go` you can instead take the two steps separately by first calling `go build main.go` and then trying to run `main.exe`. This will fail when Windows deletes your executable right after creation. I have seen compiled DLLs disappear after over a minute, when I thought I was safe, so beware that the executable might not be deleted **right away**, but maybe seconds or even minutes after compilation.

When you call `go run main.go` it will build the executable in a temporary folder under your `%APPDATA%`'s `Local` path, in a folder called `go-build`.

You might want to create an exception rule in your Windows defender to ignore `go-build` folders in your `APPDATA`. You should also exclude `GOPATH` and `GOBIN` from anti-virus scanning, you probably will build and run code there as well.